# Populating a Text Field with a Selected Cell from a Separate Table View Controller

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, protocols, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a working app which just needs some modification. It's a basic app with a Table View Controller that gets populated when a user taps the Plus button and fills in some information into text fields. The user will enter a name and event and I've made life easier by creating table view cells under the text fields so that when a user starts typing, it auto populates with the same names the user has entered before.

I'm using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController. I'm modifying the app to be more seamless now for the user. Instead of the keyboard popping up when selecting the text field, I'm taking the user modally to another Table View Controller where the user can search, create or just select an existing entry from the Table View Cells.

I've got the new table view controller appearing and displaying the existing entries using NSFetchedResultsController and that's working well.

My question is: how do I go about selecting a Cell in the new Table View Controller and having that selection of the cell do two things:

1) Dismiss the Modal View
2) Populate the name text field (in the view controller that brought up the new Table View) with the selected name from the table view controller (that came up modally).

I have this working if the table view is in the same view controller, but I'm not quite sure how I would go about extracting that information from the other table view controller.

I'm guessing I would use protocols but I'm quite a newbie and so any pointing in the right direction or even some simple sample code would be massively appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement delegate protocol.

The idea is VC1 should conform the delegate (i.e. need to have a procedure -(void)dataAvail:(NSString *)data withViewController:(ViewController *)sender{...}). VC1 will push VC2 and set VC2.delegate = self.

In VC2, when cell is selected, just call [self.delegate dataAvail:self.yourTextField.text withViewController:self];

Now, in your VC1, you should implement dataAvail... just get the value and dismiss your modal VC2.

For more info on how to declare the protocol, just google for "ios delegate tutorial". delegate Protocol is used everywhere when coding for iOS (like MVC or KVC).

Comment: Thanks Armand - that does make sense.. I've found some tutorials and I'm going to have to try work through this

Comment: @Lavanya Perfect ! if you are ok with my answer please flag it as accepted, like this other people will not spent time to found an other answer to provide. Good coding